# Using R double colon operator messes up the indentation in emacs

Tags: ess

Using R double colon operator messes up the indentation in ess/emacs. For example,

```
df <- map(
    xyz,
    something
)
```

vs.

```
df <- purrr::map(
                 xyz,
                 something)
```

where the first style is what I want. My settings are as follows:

```
'(ess-indent-from-lhs t t)
'(ess-offset-arguments (quote (prev-line 2)) t)
'(ess-offset-arguments-newline (quote (prev-line 2)) t)
'(ess-set-style (quote RStudio-))
```

How can I get ESS to treat package::function() the same as function()?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/916